# Stink bug repellent

Tags: bugs

Does anyone know of an all natural way to get rid of stink bugs? I know they are harmless but, they seem to really like my house. I don't want to kill them, I just want them to go away.

Comment: It seems you'd have a job trying to [kill them with pesticides even if you wanted to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug#Control)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few ideas or you to ponder.

> 1. Plant or move fruit trees and vegetable gardens, especially tomato plants, away from your home to prevent stink bugs from landing on the exterior of your home. - [10 Ways to Fend Off Stink Bugs](https://patch.com/maryland/columbia/10-ways-to-fend-off-stink-bugs)
> 2. Check your attic for holes or gaps and close them up. Stinkbugs often enter through attics - [10 Ways to Fend Off Stink Bugs](https://patch.com/maryland/columbia/10-ways-to-fend-off-stink-bugs)

The following may also be helpful:

> 1. **Sprinkle Diatomaceous Earth**. Spread this chalky powder both outside and inside, focusing on entryways like windows and doors along with other areas where stink bugs seem to gather.
> 2. **Make a garlic spray**. Mix 2 cups (500 ml) water with 4 tsp (20 ml) garlic powder in a spray bottle. Spray this solution onto plant leaves, windowsills, and other areas stink bugs frequent.
> 3. **Keep stink bugs away with mint**. Mix 2 cups (500 ml) of water with 10 drops of mint oil in a spray bottle. Spray the solution around possible entryways and hide-outs.
> 4. **Use catnip**. Sprinkle catnip powder around your garden and home, focusing on areas that are prone to stink bug infestation.
> 5. **Spray the stink bugs with soapy water**. Mix 32 oz (1000 ml) hot water with 3/4 cup (180 ml) mild dish soap. Spray this solution directly onto stink bugs or in areas where stink bugs gather.
> 6. **Use neem oil**. Combine 32 oz (1000 ml) warm water with 1 to 2 tsp (5 to 10 ml) neem oil in a spray bottle. Coat leaves, windowsills, and other potential entryways or hiding spots with this solution. [How to Get Rid of Stink Bugs Naturally](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Stink-Bugs-Naturally)

Do not forget to seal off your doors and windows.

> The most common entryways for stink bugs include windows, doors, baseboards, and ceiling lights. Filling gaps or correcting loose seals should significantly decrease the number of stink bugs roaming through your home. [How to Get Rid of Stink Bugs Naturally](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Rid-of-Stink-Bugs-Naturally)